# Sybase ASE using windows authentication

Tags: ado.net, sybase, sap-ase

In Sybase ASE version 15 or above, and connecting to Sybase using ADO .net.
Is it possible to login to Sybase ASE using Windows authentication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SAP/Sybase ASE 15.+ support LDAP and Kerberos.  15.5+ supports those, along with LDAPS and PAM.  Check out the manual section that covers [external authentication](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/topic/com.sybase.infocenter.dc31654.1550/html/sag1/X36173.htm) for more details on how to configure it.

http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/topic/com.sybase.infocenter.dc31654.1550/html/sag1/X36173.htm